# Angular2 Routing Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'visitExpression'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been struggling with this error for quite sometime now. After extensive research I am unable to find any other reference to it. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I believe the issue has to do with how I am using routing and the auth0 service combined. Note that none of my routing is being displayed, but my navigation bar and such are.

**EDIT:**
Originally I was under the Assumption that Auth0 has something to do with this issue. I have since removed all Auth0 components,services,imports from application. So for whatever reason the routing just isn't working at all.... I have updated the code posted so its easier to pick threw.

ERROR

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property 'visitExpression' of undefined or null reference
(http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:26) at  Anonymous function
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';    
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ appRouterProviders]);
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePageHeaderComponent } from './homepageheader.component';    
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<header></header><router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],


})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.routes.ts*

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageContentComponent } from './homepagecontent.component';
import { LoggedInComponent } from './loggedin.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [

{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomePageContentComponent },
{ path: 'loggedIn', component: LoggedInComponent },
{ path: 'loggedOut', component: LogoutComponent },

];

export const appRouterProviders = [
provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**Systemjs.config**

```
(function (global) {
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app/components', //'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },



};
var ngPackageNames = [
  'common',
  'compiler',
  'core',
  'forms',
  'http',
  'platform-browser',
  'platform-browser-dynamic',
  'router',
  'router-deprecated',
  'upgrade',
];
// Individual files (~300 requests):
function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
// Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
// Add package entries for angular packages
ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
};
System.config(config);
})(this);
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
 "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
 "angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^1.3.2"
}
}
```

Comment: I think the first route should have `pathMatch: 'full'` `{ path: '', component: HomePageContentComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },` but no idea if this fixes your issue. I don't see anything obvious wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the the issue! in my other components that I was attempting to route to, I had empty selector tags. For example here are my paths

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomePageContentComponent },
{ path: 'loggedIn', component: LoggedInComponent },
{ path: 'loggedOut', component: LogoutComponent },
```

In my LoggedInComponent and LogoutComponent I had

```
selector:'',
```

This was causing the 'visitexpression' error. So simply removing those from the components fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something obvious found ;-)

Don't import from

```
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

use instead

```
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
```

You might also need to fix your systemjs config.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and looking into this. I had changed all the things you mentioned and forgot to through up the edit! I will also add my systemjs.config in the edit as well. but changing these few things didnt work :/

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: no, I have attempted but plunker is dying before it can load my project. I will keep attempting to cut down my project to just the core components for plunker

Comment: Stripping down to a minimal repo would be the main task for creating a Plunker anyway. Please don't expect anyone to investigate a Plunker that contains a lot of code.

Comment: Not getting a whole lot of luck with plunker, its giving me URL blocked errors. I am assuming its because of the security restriction from my work. I mayhave to wait till I get home. however I did edit with my config and package.json files.

Comment: Try to mock access to real servers with services that just return some dummy data.

Comment: `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",` `beta.2` is available. Remove `router-deprecated` entries everywhere if you don't use it.

Comment: ok updated to .2 and no more references to router-deprecated. Just noticed this. on "npm start" I get no errors from page (but still no routing shows), I dont actually get the error till I refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.